# Why can't I execute the command `file /sbin/init`?

Tags: command-line, java, oracle

I'm trying to install Oracle JRE/JDK using the instructions given here [Install Oracle Java JRE on Ubuntu](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JRE-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

I need it as Android Studio recommends it.

Anyway, when I type in  `file /sbin/init` in the terminal, it just displays

```
/sbin/init: symbolic link to /lib/systemd/systemd
```

while the above link says that it should display the bit version of my OS.

Could someone tell me how to rectify this issue?

Comment: When I try the command you specified (the first one), it's working for me (Ubuntu Server 14.04). Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, but the version 16.04 LTS

Comment: that's because 14.04 doesn't use systemd as init @grooveplex (afaik this is still the case anyway)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You executed the command successfully, and it gave you accurate information.

```
$ file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: symbolic link to /lib/systemd/systemd
```

The tutorial advises you simply to find the ELF type of a binary file, one that must represent your system's architecture. Systemd is Ubuntu 16.04's init system. You can find the architecture of the regular file pointed to by the symlink with this command (thanks to muru for [pointing out the `-L` flag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814056/why-cant-i-execute-the-command-file-sbin-init/814059?noredirect=1#comment1603913_814059) which causes `file` to follow symlinks):

```
file -L /sbin/init
```

for me outputs:

```
/lib/systemd/systemd: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=dfc32dfa86e4694a0408bd227e8f91d2acbbc11a, stripped
```

Ah!

You can also get your system's bitwidth with this command, for example (there are many other ways, for example `uname -i`):

```
$ getconf LONG_BIT
64
```

another nice clean way suggested by @Serg:

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

---

As requested, here's how I install Oracle Java when I *really* need to use it instead of the much preferable OpenJDK:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: Instead of `file $(readlink ...)`, do `file -L`: "option causes symlinks to be followed".

Answer (score 3):

The commandline from the site you linked is showing you how to determine your OS type, 64bit or 32bit.  Check your OS type with this cli:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
```

By the way, I get a `required argument missing` error when I type the /sbin/init command.

You don't need those steps on that page to install Android Studio from Google on your system.  The Android studio is a tar file you download.  You open the root folder of the tar and just run the `studio.sh` from the bin folder of the archive.

There's nothing to install.

You can install an alternate JDK with:

(https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: I did all that already and android studio is installed. And after I opened it, I got a message saying that it works the best with Oracle JDK. So I'm doing all this.

Comment: You don't have to remove your current java installation to install a different one.  You can just install an alternate one and use the cli: `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to chose the one you want to use by default.  I'll add formatted steps for installing the Oracle JDK package to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that would be great:) Right now, this is what I get when I type in that command. https://s4.postimg.org/txhtb5nr1/Screenshot_from_2016_08_19_11_45_05.png

Comment: Apparently you have the oracle jdk installed.  Choose option # 1 at the command prompt in your picture.

Comment: What's the difference between option 0 and option 2? Here's a better screenshot. https://s4.postimg.org/j738ngrhp/image.png

Comment: Did you test running `1`?   It appears that `0` and `2` are more runtime while the option `1` is the development kit.  What happens when you choose `1` then run android-studio?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44181/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-harsha).

Comment: For anyone interested, The conversation proceeded in chat.  My original answer resolved the issue to use the provided steps to install Oracle java.

Comment: @harsha Glad you got your problem resolved!